# Removing an Object from a DataSource

Tags: asp.net, button, buttonclick

I am trying to remove an item which is selected in a datagrid from the domaindatasource that it uses, through a button click.

The code for the button click is:

```
 private void medItemRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (medicineInventoryDataGrid.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                MedicineInventory M = (MedicineInventory)medicineInventoryDataGrid.SelectedItem;

                MedicineInventory toRemove = (from a in ctx.MedicineInventories where (a.MedicineInventoryId == M.MedicineInventoryId) select a).Single();

                ctx.MedicineInventories.Remove(toRemove);               

            }
        }
```

However on clicking, I get the following error:

> "The Specific Entity is not contained in the EntitySet."

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is ctx? Are you using an ORM? Which one? Do you try to delete from database?

Comment: Is `toRemove` valid once you have retrieved it?

Comment: There should probably be a call to `ctx.SaveChanges()` (or similar) once you have called `context.Animals.Remove(item);` to persist your changes.

Comment: toRemove is indeed Valid, i have checked.
Adding submitchanges gets the following error "Sequence contains no elements"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 MedicineInventory M = (MedicineInventory)medicineInventoryDataGrid.SelectedItem.DataItem;
```

Comment: I get " 'object' does not contain a definition for 'DataItem' " when trying that.